# Python: (Writing Output to CSV)

Tags: python, selenium, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have been studying web scraping and I choose youtube datasets since its easily accessible

How can I write my scraped output to CSV since I'm so confused on where should I use the write.writerows?

The sample code below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

urls = [
    'https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC8butISFwT-Wl7EV0hUK0BQ',
    'https://www.youtube.com/user/thenewboston',
    'https://www.youtube.com/user/gotreehouse',
    'https://www.youtube.com/user/derekbanas',
    'https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCWr0mx597DnSGLFk1WfvSkQ',
    'https://www.youtube.com/user/ProgrammingKnowledge'
  ]

def scriptscrapejprh():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/Phong/Desktop/chromedriver.exe')
    for url in urls:
        driver.get('{}/videos?view=0&sort=p&flow=grid'.format(url))
        content = driver.page_source.encode('utf-8').strip()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')
        titles = soup.findAll('a',id='video-title')
        views = soup.findAll('span',class_='style-scope ytd-grid-video-renderer')
        video_urls = soup.findAll('a',id='video-title')
        print('Channel: {}'.format(url))
        i = 0 # views and time
        j = 0 # urls
        for title in titles[:20]:
            print('\n{}\t{}\t{}\thttps://www.youtube.com{}'.format(title.text, views[i].text, 
views[i+1].text, video_urls[j].get('href')))
            i+=2
            j+=1               

scriptscrapejprh()
```

And this is the sample output(I can't include the links):

```
Channel: ProgrammingKnowledge

C Programming Tutorial | Learn C programming | C language       5.5M views      4 years ago     -link-

Java Tutorial For Beginners 1 - Introduction and Installing the java (JDK) Step by Step Tutorial    4.1M views  5 years ago     -link-

How to create Partition on Windows 10 | Partition Hard Drives   3.2M views      3 years ago     -link-

Android Tutorial for Beginners 1 # Introduction and Installing and Configuring Java JDK 2.9M views  5 years ago -link-

How to Install Java JDK on Windows 10 ( with JAVA_HOME )        2M views        5 years ago     -link-

How to Convert Video Files using VLC Media Player       1.6M views      6 years ago     -link-

How To Install MySQL on Windows 10      1.6M views      3 years ago     -link-

Python Tutorial for Beginners 1 - Getting Started and Installing Python (For Absolute Beginners)    1.6M views  6 years ago     -link-

Beginners MS Access Database Tutorial 1 - Introduction and Creating Database    1.6M views      6 years ago
```

Comment: Did you try making the result a dictionary and export that as csv?

Comment: I will try to do this even though it is already solved. Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `writerows` function inside the second loop. Try the below code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

urls = [
    'https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC8butISFwT-Wl7EV0hUK0BQ',
    'https://www.youtube.com/user/thenewboston',
    'https://www.youtube.com/user/gotreehouse',
    'https://www.youtube.com/user/derekbanas',
    'https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCWr0mx597DnSGLFk1WfvSkQ',
    'https://www.youtube.com/user/ProgrammingKnowledge'
  ]

data_file = open("data.csv", "w", newline="", encoding='utf-8')
writer = csv.writer(data_file, delimiter=",")


def scriptscrapejprh():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/Phong/Desktop/chromedriver.exe')
    for url in urls:
        driver.get('{}/videos?view=0&sort=p&flow=grid'.format(url))
        content = driver.page_source.encode('utf-8').strip()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')
        titles = soup.findAll('a',id='video-title')
        views = soup.findAll('span',class_='style-scope ytd-grid-video-renderer')
        video_urls = soup.findAll('a',id='video-title')
        print('Channel: {}'.format(url))
        i = 0 # views and time
        j = 0 # urls
        for title in titles[:20]:
            print('\n{}\t{}\t{}\thttps://www.youtube.com{}'.format(title.text, views[i].text, 
views[i+1].text, video_urls[j].get('href')))
            writer.writerow([title.text, views[i].text, views[i+1].text, "https://www.youtube.com/{0}".format(video_urls[j].get('href'))])
            i+=2
            j+=1

    data_file.close()

scriptscrapejprh()
```

Comment: The revised code definitely solved my question. Lastly, how can I save the "data.csv" to a specific location since it saves in the Account's desktop?

Comment: You can add the full path that you want to save the file to the open function's first parameter : `data_file = open("<YOUR_FULL_FILE_PATH>", "w", newline="", encoding='utf-8')`

Comment: My pleasure. :) Have a great day to you too!

Comment: I accidentally deleted my comment. Have a great day ahead. Thank you again! :)